# "Connection not secure" error occurs when I visit websites outside the firewall in VM

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, vmware

I want to transfer packet flow in virtual machine to the host proxy, because my host can visit websites outside the firewall by proxy settings.
**Settings on Windows:**
I download clash for windows and turn on the "Allow LAN" option (other options remain default). My host and VM communicate by NAT connection way. I confirm they are in the same subnet and can ping each other successfully. 
**Settings on CentOS(VM):**
I turn on the network proxy option and set HTTP Proxy, HTTPS Proxy and Socks Host to *[MyHostIp]:[Port displayed in clash]*. 
**Problem:**
When I visit websites inside the firewall it works fine. But when I visit websites outside the firewall (eg.google.com), the firefox browser alerts "connection not secure" and just displays a blank page without content. 
The browser shows as [`http://google.com//` blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtLlh.png), the Page Info shows as [`http://google.com//` page info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id1vn.png) when I visit `http://google.com//` while the browser shows as [`https://www.google.com` page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wvx.png) the Page Info remains the same as before when I visit `https://www.google.com`.
I have tried to follow the instructions in this link [I found a fix for "Your connection is not secure"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232718).

Comment: if you go to one of these sites, and then in firefox look at the certificate in use (click on the padlock > More Info > View Certificate) what is the subject name and issuer for the certificate? is it the Proxy server?

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? HTTP will give this warning.

Comment: @FrankThomas when I visit sites outside the firewall, I click on the padlock > More Info, but in the Security tab page of Page Info, I didn't see View Certicate button. The Website Identity zone shows "Verified by: Not specified". I inserted a pic link in my post.

Comment: does the url start with https:// if you click into the address bar of the browser?

Comment: @FrankThomas no, the full url is `http://google.com`. I typed `https://www.google.com` again the page shows "Secure Connection Failed" and alerts PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Comment: so google likely has HSTS implemented (which forces HTTPS), and your HTTPS proxy isn't working properly. so when you get the Connection reset error, what does the certificate say?

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry to take a long time to reply. just like the pic I visit `google.com`, displayed as "Verified by: Not specified". the left info are the same as before except that when I visit `https://www.google.com`, the Page Info has a Media tab page which loaded a warning svg file.